# Best practices for NUnit run tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll, nunit

We have a big .Net solution(by big, I mean, 1.8 million of line of code, ~300 projects). We were having some UnitTests before(very small coverage) with MsTests, and we decided to take the unit testing seriously than before, now, every new part of the code should have coded unit tests.

We decided to use NUnit also.

My question is: Now we have a whole bunch of NUnit tests, and we would like to run them every night(we have a TFS build machine for that).

The issue we are having is the following:
We have some projects that does some dynamic loading of DLL(searching all DLL in a subfolder by example), and some of the units tests needs to have those DLL loaded in order to return the expected result.

Currently, we have an Output Directory, which all our projects are targeting. In this output directory, we have a subfolder for the units tests:

```
Debug/x86
 - /sub folder for dynamic loading one/
 - /sub folder for dynamic loading two/
 - /sub folder for dynamic loading three/
 - /sub folder with DLL not loaded with dynamic but [with probing element app.config][1]/
 - /UnitTests/
 - /lot of DLL
 - /Some executable of our solutions
```

Currently, our tests are failing because we test some DLL on the root of the lib, but the dynamically loaded DLL cannot be found.

What is the best practice here?
I can imagine a few scenario:

- Put the UnitTest in the root directory
- Copy(post build event) DLL in the UnitTest directory
- Another magic trick that allow us to references some folder in our "parent" folder?

Answer (score 1):

Run the tests with the Appbase set to the root. How to accomplish this depends on your method of running tests, which isn't stated. For example, if you use nunit3-console there are command-line arguments or with the NUnit3 VS adapter you can use a .runsettings file.